# Javascript function assigned to object cannot access inherited method

Tags: javascript

I'm no doubt doing something dumb here, but the following code results in an

```
error "this.getString is not a function."
```

This occurs because when `unrelatedInstance` calls `stringGetter`, "`this`" in `showCombinedStrings()` has the value of `Unrelated`....which actually seems fair enough, but how could this be set up so that it would work?

```
function BaseStringGetter() {
    this.getString = function () {
        return 'this is from BaseStringGetter';    
    }
}

function DerivedStringGetter() {
    this.showCombinedStrings = function () {
        console.log( 'this is from DerivedStringGetter and... ' + this.getString() );
    }
}
DerivedStringGetter.prototype = new BaseStringGetter();
var stringGetterInstance = new DerivedStringGetter();

function Unrelated() {};
var unrelatedInstance = new Unrelated();
unrelatedInstance.stringGetter = stringGetterInstance.showCombinedStrings;
unrelatedInstance.stringGetter();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are calling `unrelatedInstance.stringGetter();`

Even though stringGetter refers to the `showCombinedStrings` function, `this` inside `showCombinedStrings` now refers to the `unrelatedInstance` instance which does not have the `toString()` property that is why the error.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jcgc0pgd/4/)

Here the value of `this` is printed as `Unrelated {stringGetter: function}` which is not an `DerivedStringGetter` instance

---

One easy solution is to use .bind() to give a custom execution context to `unrelatedInstance.stringGetter` like

```
unrelatedInstance.stringGetter = stringGetterInstance.showCombinedStrings.bind(stringGetterInstance);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jcgc0pgd/)

Now even if you call `unrelatedInstance.stringGetter()`, `this` inside `showCombinedStrings` will refer to the `stringGetterInstance` instance.

Answer (score 1):

One option is this:

```
unrelatedInstance.stringGetter =
    stringGetterInstance.showCombinedStrings.bind(stringGetterInstance);
unrelatedInstance.stringGetter();
```

Here, you're using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make `this` inside of `unrelatedInstance.stringGetter()` always refer back to `stringGetterInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function on an object, `this` will refer to the object the function is invoked on even if the function was originally defined elsewhere.

When you call `unrelatedInstance.stringGetter();`, `this` inside the function will now refer to `unrelatedInstance` which doesn't have `getString()`. The [MDN this reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method) has more info.

You could do something like this to preserve the original context:

```
unrelatedInstance.stringGetter = function() {
    return stringGetterInstance.showCombinedStrings();
}
```

Edit: I left out `bind` that the other answers have now mentioned since it doesn't exist in IE8 but you'd be fine using that if you have a shim or don't care about old browsers.